# Outline for required reputation for capabilities

Tags: discussion

When a user receives a new capability, a little banner appears at the top with a "More Info" link. On that page, there is a breakdown of reputation required for certain capabilities.

How can I navigate to that page without the banner popup? I cannot seem to find it from within my profile or on WPSE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hover with the mouse over your name and click on the privileges link:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I must have been too quick to get to the profile page that I missed it. Oddly, the "privileges" link is not present for WPSE Meta. https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-4hAfcHC03vo/T5VwvDn4cwI/AAAAAAAAAXA/gyX5uDq3GHU/s391/1335193771465.png

Comment: I think that's because - although *badges* are awarded separately between main site and meta - meta privileges are redundant (although sometimes a bit out-of-synch) with main-site privileges. If you add a `meta` subdomain to the privileges URL, it simply redirects to the main-site privileges page.